# How to write a config file from a Swift command line tool?

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line-interface, plist

I am building a command line tool using Swift. I want to store user configs into a plist.

I figured out I can use `Copy Files Phase` under `Build Phase` to copy the plist, so that I can access it at runtime like:

```
guard let tempPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "config", ofType:"plist") else {
            printError("Cannot locate config file")
            exit(-1)
        }
self.configPath = tempPath
self.configDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: self.configPath) as! [String:String]
```

After getting user information, I also can successfully update that plist by:

```
do {
    let pData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(
                        fromPropertyList: self.configDict,
                        format: .xml,
                        options: 0)

    try pData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.configPath))

    } catch {
        printError("Failed to write dictionary to property list")
        return
    }
```

However, after the process completes, the original plist is not changed at all. So I guess what Xcode does is to copy the plist into product directory, then delete that copy after completion?

How can I write user configs into a plist in Swift command line tool?

Comment: Command line tools don't have a bundle.